# How to use props and a user token in one js function?

Tags: reactjs, token, access-token

I am looking for a solution where it is possible to use props and a user token to create a dynamic Dialog window for changing the users meta data (e.g. password).

When I click the button in the profile view

```
<ChangeRequestDialog changerequest="Password"></ChangeRequestDialog>
```

It sets the changerequest to password so that the dialog knows that the user would like to change the password and renders the Dialog window accordingly.

```
export default function ChangeRequestDialog(props, token){
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setModel(event.target.value);
  };
const pwrecovery = async (e) => {
    let { data, error } = await supabase.auth.resetPasswordForEmail(
      token.user.email
    );
    console.log('pw recovery done')
  };

return (
<React.Fragment>
<Button className="button" variant="contained" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                      change password
                    </Button>
<Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>change {props.changerequest}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
{ props.changerequest=='Password'
                      ? "Are you sure you want to change you password?"
: ""
                  }
</DialogContentText>
 <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
          {
                     props.changerequest=='Password'
                      ? <Button onClick={pwrecovery}>Change</Button>
                      : ""
                  }
        </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
```

I am passing the token from App.js to the ChangeRequestDialog.js like this:

```
function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(false);

  if (token) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(token));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("token")) {
      let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("token"));
      setToken(data);
    }
  }, []);
return (
<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
<Route path="/profile" element={<Profile token={token} />} />
<Route path="/ChangeRequestDialog" element={<ChangeRequestDialog token={token} />} />
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

everything worked out fine so far except from the pwrecovery function as it drops the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')" I suppose this error occures because I do not pass on the token correctly I have tried:

```
export default function ChangeRequestDialog(props, {token}){
```

The result is that the function stops one instance earlier and the error says: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')"
On other pages I do it like that and it works perfectly fine:

```
const Profile = ({ token }) => {
};
export default Profile;
```

The Token is set when the user logs in
App.js:

```
<Route path="/login" element={<Login setToken={setToken} />} />
```

Login.jsx:

```
const Login=({setToken}) =>{
...
async function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    try{
      const {data, error} = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword(
        {
          email: formData.email,
          password: formData.password,
        }
        )

      if (error) throw error
      console.log(data)
      setToken(data)
      navigate('/profile')
    }
      catch(error){
        alert(error)
      }
}
return(...)}
```

but I guess because of the function the syntax is different. Would love to get an answer thank you in advance!

Comment: try {token, ...props}

Answer (score 1):

The way your passing the props is incorrect, the way your doing it now react interpets the first param (props) as the props object and token will be undefined
there are 2 ways to fix it

1. use props.token

```
export default function ChangeRequestDialog(props){
 const token = props.token;
...
}
```

2. destructure in place

```
export default function ChangeRequestDialog({token, ...props}){
....
}
```

Comment: Hello Quak_2023,
thank you for your answer. Unfortunately these did not worked out, I still get the message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')". The Token is set when the user log in. I have updated the question with this information maybe it helps to get a better understanding of my project.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include the part where you have to change the way your passing the props to make this solution work, but i see you figured it out already

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Quak_2023!

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution! Additionally to Quak_2023's answer I have added "token={token}" to the ChangeRequestDialog call in the Profile.js which looks now like that:

```
<ChangeRequestDialog changerequest="Mitgliedsmodel" token={token}></ChangeRequestDialog>
```